# Is it possible to see AI's city gets captured by barbarians?

Tags: civilization-5

I've tried the following setting: huge map, only one AI as Venice, raging barbarians, one-city challenge, no city-state, level 5. I expected the barbarians will capture the capital of Venice because of the number of encampments and the high spawning speed. Also during the game, Venice has built Great Library and Parthenon. So I think he was not on the track of military sciences. But even with this, I didn't see the barbarians capturing his capture. So is it possible to see barbarians conquering an AI?

Answer (score 8):

Barbarians cannot capture cities; if they bring the city to zero health, they "plunder" it, making you lose gold.

Barbarians rarely attack cities, by the way - they prefer to pillage improvements and to capture your workers (and other non-combat units).

Comment: They will capture settlers also. I found some Barbarian settlers and when I moved a military unit onto them I had a choice of capturing them for myself or returning them to their original civ.

Comment: @DavidYell yes, barbarians capture settlers (and other kinds of non-combat units) but I don't see how that is related to the question or my answer.

Comment: I thought it was relevant as you said "capture your workers". Perhaps it needs an edit to say "kinds of non-combat units" ?

Comment: @DavidYell ah okay, I see what you mean. Edited!